# VS 2010 C# comment task doesn't appear if its behind comment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

To add a task in task list, all I have to do just write `//todo : [message]`. But problem happens if this line gets commented, then that task just disappears.

Eg.

Working one

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello");//todo : text text
```

Not working one

```
//MessageBox.Show("Hello");//todo : text text
```

What actually happens is when I want to disable some code temporary so I comment it out. But then I lost the task comment inside and have to search manually with Ctrl + F for all todos.

Answer (score 1):

Task list tokens need to be at the beginning of the comment and nested comments aren't seen as new comments.

Put the `//todo` on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/*MessageBox.Show("Hello"); //todo : text text*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this type of Comment:

```
//todo : text ext
//MessageBox.Show("Hello");
```